# Pygame Sprite transparency collision

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I would like to create physics body around the physical paths of the texture (cutting out alpha channel). How to do it in pygame? Is it going to be effective?

```py
player_idle = pygame.image.load('data\img\player\idle\idle-1.png')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `mask` module, especially the [`pygame.mask.from_surface()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html) function:

> Creates a Mask object from the given surface by setting all the opaque pixels and not setting the transparent pixels.

Then you can store the resulting [`Mask`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask) object as `mask`-attribute in your Sprites and e.g. use [`pygame.sprite.collide_mask()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_mask) for pixel-perfect collision detection.